# How can you write a pattern rule for GNU make that will only match directories?

Tags: gnu-make

I thought that using a rule like this

```
out/%/:
    @ echo "Should be a directory: " $@
```

would only match targets with a trailing slash. But

```
$ make out/index.html
Should be a directory:  out/index.html
```

Is there a way to write the target in a pattern rule so that only directories will match it?

Comment: Never used this syntax myself but `%/.` seems plausible.

Comment: I can't say for certain but I would be surprised if there was a way to do this. make doesn't deal with directories much (and their properties make their interaction with make's expectations ... interesting). What are you ultimately trying to do here?

Comment: About the only sensible thing all you can do with a directory in make is to create it when it doesn't exist. Using some sort of marker file is the make friendly way to do this. `%/.sentinel: ; mkdir $* && touch $@` or somesuch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a kind of hacky way write a pattern that will only match directories. The `$(dir names...)` function will return a pattern that matches only directories. And listing the same thing multiple times is the in a target is same as listing it once. So for example:

```
 TARGETS=$(dir out/*)
 $TARGETS: 
     @ echo "Should be a directory: " $@
```